# Unable to call controller method using kendo file upload

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

This my kendo grid, where I'm using client detail template to display expanded row. Inside that I need file upload.

This is my view page code.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Fundraiser.Web.Models.ProductDescriptors>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {       
        columns.Bound(item => item.ProductName).Title("Product").Width(225);
        columns.Bound(item => item.Quantity).Title("Sale Item Quantity").Width(125);
    })
        .Pageable()
        .Sortable()
        .Scrollable(scrolling => scrolling.Height("auto"))
        .ClientDetailTemplateId("client-template")
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(10)
        .Read(read => read.Action("GetProductDetails_Read", "Product").Data("additionalInfo"))
        )
)

<script id="client-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
@(Html.Kendo().Upload()
                .Name("fileUpload")                    
                .Async(a => a
                .Save("UploadFile", "Product")
                .Remove("UploadFile", "Product")
                .AutoUpload(true)
                )
                .ToClientTemplate()
            )

</script>
```

I'm unable to call the controller method using this kendo upload.

```
[HttpPost]
public void UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase fileUpload)
{
    //Upload file in to server
}
```

Comment: did you check that kendo don't try to upload using GET method ?

Comment: yes I tried, it didn't worked.

Comment: i built a sample project to test your code and everything work fine. The only difference is that i don't have any `additionalInfo` method call on read.